# How to execute a shortcode within a custom field?

Tags: php, custom-field, shortcode

I am using a plugin that generates a shortcode to display files from a Dropbox folder. I need to display the shortcode on a specific page, but it will be different for each user.

Therefore I have created a custom field for each user, called 'view_files_shortcode'.

I thought I could then call this user custom field on the page, and it would display whatever was set for each user. However it just displays the actual shortcode.

Currently I am using this:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
$userid = get_current_user_id();
get_userdata( $userid );  
get_field('view_files_shortcode', 'user_'. $userid );}?>
<?php the_field('view_files_shortcode', 'user_'. $userid ); ?>
```

Can anyone tell me how to make the shortcode execute? Thank you.

Comment: You can use `do_shortcode()` - see the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Using `the_field();` will just return the content of that field (guessing it's just text field?).

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $userid = get_current_user_id();
    get_userdata($userid);
    $shortcode = get_field('view_files_shortcode', 'user_' . $userid);
}
?>
<?php echo do_shortcode($shortcode); ?>
```